# get the indices in a C++ mdspan from a reference by arithmetic

Tags: c++, tensor, c++23, mdspan

```
#include <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kokkos/mdspan/single-header/mdspan.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main(){
    std::vector vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 88, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    auto ms = std::mdspan(vec.data(), 2, 6);

//given the indices in the tensor, get the position in contiguous memory
    {
        const int position = std::distance(vec.data(), &ms[1, 3]);
        std::cout << position << '\n';
    }
//given the position in contiguous memory, get the indices in the tensor by direct access ?
    {    
        const int position = 9;
        //I wanted to avoid doing the arithmetic myself ? something like auto [i, j] = ms.indices_from_pos(position) ?
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one can be simply spelled as `const int position = ms.mapping()(1, 3);`

Comment: the mapping only works in this direction ? Is there a reverse mapping ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert: The forward mapping is easy (just follow the extents). The reverse mapping is very hard in general. This case is fairly simple. Although the extent is dynamic, the span is unique, exhaustive and has stride 1.  But a method like you propose would have to work for _every_ (dynamic) extent. It would have to invert the `LayoutPolicy` of your `mdspan`, even if that's user-specified